# Reducing Emacs delay after error

Tags: emacs

I'm using an emacs-lisp script that has a minor bug which causes it to sometimes choke with an error message, and then execution proceeds without problem. The error itself does not bother me, what annoys me is that Emacs remains 10-15 seconds blocked after that and I must wait for what I believe to be some timer (designed to ensure I see the error message before it disappears) to end before I can resume my editing.

Is there a simple way to reduce this delay? I couldn't find where this timer is defined in order to change its value.

Some additional information:

- I'm using Emacs 23.2, but I tried recompiling and using 23.4, it didn't change anything;
- I tried Emacs 24.1 and the error disappeared, but I had a huge performance impact (the script has been designed for Emacs 23.2), so the "wait for error" is still a better option than using 24.1;
- The script in question will be updated by its author sometime in the future, but I'm looking for a quick and dirty solution meanwhile.
- The error message is: "error in process filter: Attempt to delete minibuffer or sole ordinary window".

Comment: Tell the author of the 3rd-party-script (What does that mean in Emacs anyway?) and help him fix it.

Comment: I'm afraid it's not as simple as that: the error message by itself shouldn't cause any delay, so there's probably some other piece of code that _does_ cause a delay, and during that time the error message remains visible.  So I think diving into the code and fixing the underlying issue is the only way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as already said, it's a bug. Please report it to the maintainer.

Beside you may look into the code for a form like

(accept-process-output &optional PROCESS SECONDS
MILLISEC JUST-THIS-ONE)

Allow any pending output from subprocesses to be read by Emacs.
It is read into the process' buffers or given to their filter functions.
Non-nil arg PROCESS means do not return until some output has been received
from PROCESS.

Non-nil second arg SECONDS and third arg MILLISEC are number of seconds
and milliseconds to wait;

;;;

Comment: Thank you very much, your message allowed me to identify a possible cause for the error and I could devise a workaround. It also helped me file a bug report with more precise information.